# Small 2D image plane disappears at short distance?

Tags: image

I’m using 2d images with alpha (opacity) as a sort of “decal” on my model, but if the camera moves even 5ish meters away, the 2d image totally vanishes from view. My clip start and end are at 0.0001m and 1000m respectively.

These decals are used for the facial features of my character so it's important they stay rendered at distance.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When your clipping maximum and minimum are too far apart you can get some glitches (hence why we need clipping in the first place). Therefore when you lower your minimum from 0.1 (default value) to 0.0001 make sure you do the same with your maximum to keep things balanced (from 1000 to 10).

Comment: Good to know, but messing with the values didn't seem to help me, unfortunately. It still disappears when the camera moves away from the character.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CBQCxYtewtpWpGcEBz-15fPP9OcdH24z/view?usp=sharing Here's my blend file.

Added pictures